# Proposition 1.10, i) in Atiyah & MacDonald's Comm. Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Can someone explain the underlined part? $a_i$ are ideals. I'm not entirely sure what is meant by the 1 (mod $a_n)$.[image]

Comment: Above in the text says something like: *If $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal, and $x$ and $y$ are elements of the ring, then the whole expression “$x \equiv y \pmod{\mathfrak{a}}$” means $x-y \in \mathfrak a$*.

Comment: So is the claim here that $\Pi_{i=1}^{n-1} (1-y_i) - 1 \in a_n$? (Because each term except the first 1 in the product expanded will have some $y_i$ factors?)